# Cancan : User can see its backoffice show view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, cancan

(Using rails 4, Cancan 1.6.10)

Hello all,

I have two `UsersController`: one for the front, the other under `/backoffice` for the back, and both are using the same `User` model.

I defined abilities for a "normal user" like this :

```
can(:manage, User) do |u|
  u == user
end
```

whereas an admin user will be able to manage all users:

```
can :manage, User
```

I also have two "show" views, one in the front: `/users/:id` and one in the backoffice: `/backoffice/users/:id`

My problem is that a limited user can today see its profile through the backoffice URL, as he "can Manage this user". (And of course this is not acceptable)

I know this should not be too difficult to correct, but what solution would you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a way to namespace the abilities. See the Wiki entry of the continued project CanCanCan here: https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Authorization-for-Namespaced-Controllers

What it basically does is override the `Ability` class to pass a namespace that is determined by the   `ApplicationController`. The `Ability` class has two different rulesets depending on the namespace it is initialized with.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian, this is what I was looking for. I don't find this method really sexy, so I'm waiting a little for another answer. I will accept yours if there is no better answer.

Comment: No problem. The extension of `Ability` class is alright I'd say. The namespace determination is quite hacky though.